# how to use the ruby analytical receive binary stream from the TCP

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm going to the receiving device over the data, but these data are binary stream, I put these data storage, then read to display them correctly, is there a better way?

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|

    File.open("tmp","w") { |file| file.write(client.gets)}
    File.open("tmp").each do |f|
     puts f.unpack('H*')
    end

    client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send the time to the client
    client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
    client.close                # Disconnect from the client
  end
}
```

the received data like this: **xx^Q^A^Hb0@ <90>26  2^B^@<83>ev**

I want like this: **787811010862304020903236202032020001c26c0d0a**

sorry about my poor English！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a temporary file with a name will cause a problem if there are multiple clients sending data; the temporary file will be overwritten.

You don't need to use a temporary file.

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    puts client.gets.unpack('H*')
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send the time to the client
    client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
    client.close
  end
}
```